# Models django select one of two values

Tags: django

I need that one of them should be selected, but canot be blank both. Is it posible?

```
location     = models.ForeignKey('Location', help_text="Enter inventory location", null=True, blank=True)
assigned     = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I am thinking of 2 solutions here....1. override the `save` method to check this. 2. add default options to one or both of your fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the model in the `clean()` method. If the model is not valid, you can raise a validation error:

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.location and not self.assigned:
        raise ValidationError('Either location or assigned should be non-blank')
```

See the Django docs for more info about the clean method:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: off-topic question: what happens when a ValidationError is raised? how to catch it? what happens next? from where does the code continue to execute? where can you access the raised text error?

Comment: @MihaiZamfir In the Django admin, the ValidationError will result in an error message. If you save the model outside the admin, you should catch the exception yourself. It's just a regular Python exception so it all works like regular Python exceptions, you can read more about that in the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method in your models to handle this

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.location and not self.assigned:
        # Warn the user about the issue
    else:
        super(<your_model_name>, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```